# How can I preserve the page scroll position when opening a dialog in response to a link trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, event-handling

I would like to know how I can maintain the scroll position when I open a jQuery dialog.

Here is the code I'm using to open my dialog:

```
<a class="link" onclick="openmyDialog();" href="#">Open a dialog</a>
```

And the function :

```
function openmyDialog()
{
    $("#dialog").dialog('destroy');
    $("#dialog").html("msg");
    $("#dialog").dialog(
    {
        buttons:
        {
        "Yes": function()
              {
                $(this).dialog("close");
              }
        },
        resizable: false,
        draggable: true,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Error'
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning your return value to the click handler properly:

```
onclick="return openmyDialog();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>` instead of "#"?

Comment: That fixes a symptom, but leaves the root cause (failure to cancel the default behavior). See Greg's answer for a simple way to accomplish the latter.